# Why in angular observable timer is working locally not working after deployment?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

The below code working proper in locally but after deployment it doesn't work.

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
let somethingTimer = Observable.timer(5000);
// rest of other code.
```

After changing above code to below code working proper both locally and on production server.

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';
let somethingTimer = timer(5000);
// rest of other code.
```

Why this happen any explanation.

Configuration:

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.3
Node: 8.11.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular:
...

Package                      Version
--------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.6.3
@angular-devkit/core         0.6.3
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.6.3
@schematics/angular          0.6.3
@schematics/update           0.6.3
rxjs                         6.2.0
typescript                   2.7.2
```

**Error in console log**

> TypeError: a.timer is not a function

Comment: What do you mean by “doesn’t work”?

Comment: @martin I have updated the question with error message from console after inspecting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have RxJS 6 but you're trying to use `timer` as in RxJS 5 (RxJS 5 used now deprecated patching of the `Observable` class).

Since RxJS 6 the only way of using operators and so called "Observable creation methods" is by importing them directly from `'rxjs'` or `'rxjs/operators'` respectively:

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

let somethingTimer = timer(5000);
```

For migration docs see:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md
- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md

Comment: I have also searched for that and found https://medium.com/code-divoire/importing-rxjs-observable-functions-in-angular-5-cca1f9bac108. Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 1):

You upgraded from rxjs 5 to 6. There were many changes from 5 to 6.

The first example is rxjs 5 code and the second is how you do it in 6.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the way that "timer" is imported.
In case 1 the timer is coming from the "observable" object but on  second one is a separate let
import { timer }

in my opinion bet way is import { timer } from 'rxjs/observable/timer';

i hope to help you